# Suggestions on how to update Angular version

Tags: angular

I have an angular project which has the version 6.1
But I've installed some custom libraries using `npm`.

So my question is:
What should I take care for updating?

I mean:
Do I have to use an external tool?
Or. Should I check every library dependency for upgrading the verions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to update angular is the commandline command:

`ng update`

https://angular.io/cli/update

This updates angular and it's dependencies.

I would make a new git branch to test the update without danger.

1. `ng update`
2. update your own npm packages (one after the other)

---

If you use vscode, then i recommend the extension `Version Lens` -> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pflannery.vscode-versionlens

With that extension you see all actual versions and all possible updates in your package.json

Comment: Hi, I know that command.
But when updating will I have incompatibilities in some libraries?

Comment: It looks nice `Version Lens`.

Comment: normaly you have no problems with angular and its direct dependencies. 
But it is possible that your own additional libraries have incompatibilities.